# How to submit phonegap app on apple store using windows?

Tags: ios, cordova

i have created build of my phonegap app(by submitting certificate(.p12) file and provisioning profile on Adobe Phonegap), but when I visited to itunes connect for submission of my app I found section showing "Submit your App using XCode6 or later ,or application loader" . so my problem is I have no MAC available so is there any way to submit my app without MAC ...

[image: showing what I found in the submit section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX5Ln.png)

Comment: yeah, you need a mac, you can buy it or rent it, there are services like macincloud where you can use a remote mac to submit the app, or services that upload the ipa for you

Answer (score -1):

You need to create ipa file with production certificate and provisioning. And upload it using application loader.